# How can i refresh data immediately after updating it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, updates

so here i'm trying to to update quantity in product_inventory table that links between products and inventories,
however it's updated in the database but not in the screen until i use ctrl+S.
i tried to use many possible ways as calling the quantity in different way even in setState but none of them worked,
how can i make the data change after the quantity update.
also i'm using an API with laravel

```
class ProductsInInventoryWidget extends StatefulWidget
{
  ProductsInInventory? model;
  BuildContext? context;
  //final ValueChanged onPressed;

  ProductsInInventoryWidget({this.model,this.context});

  @override
  _ProductsInInventoryWidgetState createState() => _ProductsInInventoryWidgetState();
}



class _ProductsInInventoryWidgetState extends State<ProductsInInventoryWidget> {

  var apiCall = new APICall();
   addQuantity(String mydata) async
  {
    String Product_BarCode = widget.model!.productBarcode.toString();
    String Inventory_id = widget.model!.inventoryId.toString();
    var response = await http.put(
        Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.188:8000/api/user/IncrementProduct/"+Product_BarCode+"/"+Inventory_id,),
      body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'quantity': mydata,
      }),
    );

     // setState(() {
     //   response;
     //   mydata = widget.model!.quantity.toString();
     // });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var quantityData = widget.model!.quantity.toString();
    return InkWell(
        onTap: ()
        {
        //  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> ProductsInInventoryForm(model: widget.model)));
        },
        splashColor: Colors.amber,
        child:  Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0.0),
            child : Card(

              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 6, 5, 0),
              child: Padding(
                padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        radius:40,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
                        child: Text(quantityData
                          ,style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white
                        ),),
                      ),
                      title: Text(widget.model!.productName), //(widget.model!.ProductName!,),
                      subtitle: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [

                          Text("code bar : " + widget.model!.productBarcode ),
                          Text("updated : " +  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm').format(widget.model!.updatedAt)),
                          Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.blue,),

                                onPressed: ()async {
                                  onRefresh: () { setState((){
                                    // Update your data here
                                    addQuantity(quantityData);
                                  }); };
                                  setState(() {
                                  //  widget.onPressed;
                                    addQuantity(quantityData);
                                    quantityData = widget.model!.quantity.toString();
                                  });
                                }
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.remove,color: Colors.blue,),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Perform some action
                                },

                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Perform some action
                                },
                                child: const Text('Delete',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),),
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: because http not behave like soket.. when data change in socket it automatically change but when you receive data from http ..then you must call the http request again to get data from database

Comment: and where you receive data from database .after api request..??

Comment: i didn't really understand the second question, you mean where did i call this class with params ?

Comment: i tried this `return ProductsInInventory.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));` as response but it seems like it doesn't work, how make a respond to get the new quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution i just had to change it in the ui seperatly by changing "quantityData" to an int and increment it in the setstate, this way it keeps updating in the screen

````
class ProductsInInventoryWidget extends StatefulWidget
{
  ProductsInInventory? model;

  BuildContext? context;



  ProductsInInventoryWidget({this.model,this.context});

  @override
  _ProductsInInventoryWidgetState createState() => _ProductsInInventoryWidgetState();
}



class _ProductsInInventoryWidgetState extends State<ProductsInInventoryWidget> {



  int quantityData =1;




  Future addQuantity(int mydata) async
  {
    String Product_BarCode = widget.model!.productBarcode.toString();
    String Inventory_id = widget.model!.inventoryId.toString();
    var response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.188:8000/api/user/IncrementProduct/$Product_BarCode/$Inventory_id/$mydata",),
      body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'quantity': mydata.toString(),
      }),
    );
    var body = jsonDecode(response.body);



  }


  Future<http.Response> DeleteProductFromInventoryProducts(int join_id) async
  {
    final http.Response response = await http.delete(
      Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.188:8000/api/user/deleteProductsFromInventory/$join_id",)
    );

    return response;


  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    quantityData = widget.model!.quantity; // 2# assign the incoming data here
    super.initState();

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0.0),
        child : Card(

          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 6, 5, 0),
          child: Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    radius:40,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
                    child: Text(quantityData.toString()
                      ,style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),),
                  ),
                  title: Text(widget.model!.productName), //(widget.model!.ProductName!,),
                  subtitle: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [

                      Text("code bar : " + widget.model!.productBarcode ),
                      Text("updated : " +  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm').format(widget.model!.updatedAt)),
                      Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.blue,),

                            onPressed: () async{

                             // await addQuantity(quantityData);



                              setState(() {

                                quantityData+=1;
                                print(quantityData.toString());
                                addQuantity(quantityData);
                              });


                            }
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.remove,color: Colors.blue,),
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Perform some action
                            },

                          ),
                          FlatButton(
                            child: const Text('Delete',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),),
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Perform some action
                              setState(() {
                             //   DeleteProductFromInventoryProducts(widget.model!.id.toString());
                              });
                            },

                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future addQuantity(String mydata) async
  {
    String Product_BarCode = widget.model!.productBarcode.toString();
    String Inventory_id = widget.model!.inventoryId.toString();
    var response = await http.put(
        Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.188:8000/api/user/IncrementProduct/"+Product_BarCode+"/"+Inventory_id,),
      body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'quantity': mydata,
      }),
    );

     // setState(() {
     //   response;
     //   mydata = widget.model!.quantity.toString();
     // });

  }
```

and call method like that

```
 await addQuantity(quantityData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I did some steps on how you can resolve the issue, check the comments steps:

```
class _ProductsInInventoryWidgetState extends State<ProductsInInventoryWidget> {

  var apiCall = new APICall();
  String? quantityData;   // <--- 1# add this variable here


  Future<void> addQuantity(String mydata) async
  {
    String Product_BarCode = widget.model!.productBarcode.toString();
    String Inventory_id = widget.model!.inventoryId.toString();
    var response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.188:8000/api/user/IncrementProduct/"+Product_BarCode+"/"+Inventory_id,),
      body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'quantity': mydata,
      }),
    );

    setState(() {
      // quantityData = responseResult    6# Finally you should assing the new response data from Laravel to quantityData variable
                                          // I do not know how you are receiving this data so get the response and them add it gere.  
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    quantityData = widget.model!.quantity.toString(); // 2# assign the incoming data here
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: ()
        {
          //  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> ProductsInInventoryForm(model: widget.model)));
        },
        splashColor: Colors.amber,
        child:  Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0.0),
            child : Card(

              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 6, 5, 0),
              child: Padding(
                padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        radius:40,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
                        child: Text(quantityData!  // 3# update to null safe
                          ,style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white
                          ),),
                      ),
                      title: Text(widget.model!.productName), //(widget.model!.ProductName!,),
                      subtitle: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [

                          Text("code bar : " + widget.model!.productBarcode ),
                          Text("updated : " +  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm').format(widget.model!.updatedAt)),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.blue,),

                                  onPressed: () async {
                                      await addQuantity(quantityData!);  // 4# remove set state from here and add await to it to stop until it finishes
                                                                         // why remove setState? because you are using it in the function call
                                  }
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.remove,color: Colors.blue,),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Perform some action
                                },

                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Perform some action
                                },
                                child: const Text('Delete',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),),
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in the responseResult should i call just the quantity from the database ?

Comment: if so can u give me a random example ?

Comment: I usually use dart retrofit to fetch data, but in the flutter docs there is an example on how to do it see the link : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: or using jsonDecode in the response. Here is an example which is in the http 
package example: https://pub.dev/packages/http#using ---> here the code  example -->

var decodedResponse = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) as Map;

Comment: ---> then on decodedResponse access the data as is done on a normal Map object,  decodedResponse["quantity"], key "quantity" if this key is coming in the response...